# How to change the focus color on a component in Delphi VCL

Tags: user-interface, delphi, vcl

In Delphi VCL, by default, when you focus on a `TEdit` component, the focus color is blue:

[image]

I'd like to change this color. How can this be done?

Comment: It's not like that. It's rendered by the system. You can write a handler for the `WM_NCPAINT` message (or use and modify VCL Styles).

Comment: @Victoria Do you maybe have some code examples for this?

Comment: https://theroadtodelphi.com/2012/02/06/changing-the-color-of-edit-controls-with-vcl-styles-enabled/

Comment: your image link is broken

Comment: @RemyLebeau Doesn't seem broken on my computer. It loads perfectly.

Comment: @ShaunRoselt it was broken at the time I posted that comment. Seems to be working now. Probably a system hiccup